# Different dependencies for different branches in a Julia package?

Tags: git, julia, branch

I'm developing a Julia package, and I have a new git branch that will have different dependencies. Is it possible to add dependencies to the package on branch B, but not branch A? Currently I am using

```
pkg> activate PackageName
pkg> add DependencyPackageName
```

but this changes the Project.toml file across all branches.

Comment: That is not how git supposed to work, more likely you just mixed something (like branch names, folders, files).

Comment: I was clearly too tired last night when I had this problem. I was changing branches in Atom without pushing my changes, so I think this confused things. Now if I push changes and then switch branches, the Project.toml is as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the Atom editor to view different branches **without** pushing my changes, so I think this confused things.

The correct way to do this is to go to the branch where you want to add a dependency and add it as usual. This will only change the Project.toml file in the current branch. If you then commit the changes you will be able to switch to a different branch and see the unchanged Project.toml file.